# finding time and space complexity of the given java code

Tags: java, algorithm, language-agnostic

hi i need to find the time and space complexity of the program, pls help, if possible please suggest the optimization that can be performed, 
.........................................................................................................................................................................................

```
public class Sol {
    public int findMaxRectangleArea(int [][] as) {
        if(as.length == 0)
       return 0;
    int[][] auxillary = new int[as.length][as[0].length];
        for(int i = 0; i < as.length; ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < as[i].length; ++j) {
            auxillary[i][j] = Character.getNumericValue(as[i][j]);
        }
        }
        for(int i = 1; i < auxillary.length; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < auxillary[i].length; ++j) {
            if(auxillary[i][j] == 1)
                    auxillary[i][j] = auxillary[i-1][j] + 1;
            }
        }

    int max = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < auxillary.length; ++i) {
            max = Math.max(max, largestRectangleArea(auxillary[i]));
        }
        return max;
    }

    private int largestRectangleArea(int[] height) {
        Stack<Integer> stack =
        new Stack<Integer>();
        int max = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while(i < height.length) {
            if(stack.isEmpty() ||
                height[i] >= stack.peek()) {
                stack.push(height[i]);
            i++;
            }
            else {
            int count = 0;
            while(!stack.isEmpty() &&
                stack.peek() > height[i]) {
                    count++;
                    int top = stack.pop();
                max = Math.max(max, top * count);
                }
            for(int j = 0; j < count + 1; ++j) {
                    stack.push(height[i]);
                }
                i++;
            }
        }

        int count = 0;
        while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
            count++;
            max = Math.max(max, stack.pop() * count);
        }
        return max;
    }
```

thank you in advance

Comment: I suspect this why you're not getting any responses: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the space complexity take a look at the variables you declare and are larger than a single primitive variable. In fact I believe your space complexity will be determined my the array `auxilary` and the `Stack` `stack`. The size of the first one is pretty clear and I don't completely understand the second one but I see it's size will never be greater than the one of the array. So I would say the space complexity is `O(size of(auxilary))` or `O(N * M)` where `N=as.length()` and `M = as[0].length`.

Now the time complexity is a bit trickier. You have two cycles over the whole `auxilary` array so for sure time complexity is  at least `O( N * M)`. You also have another cycle that invokes `largestRectangleArea` for each row of `auxilary`. If I get the code in this function correctly it seems this function is again linear, but I am not sure here. Since you know the logic better probably you will be able to compute its complexity better.

Hope this helps.